# Couldn't match expected type 'Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT MongoContext IO a0' with actual type 'IO ()'

Tags: mongodb, haskell, graphviz, dot

I want to print my dot graph taken from mongoDB and then convert into an image.

```hs
run = do

    docs <- timeFilter -- function to fetch [Document] from mongoDB
    let dot = onlyDot docs -- exclude extra field from the documents
    let dotObject = getObjId dot -- convert into an object
    -- converting dot graph to string and then string to text to pass it on to parseDotGraph function
    let xDotGraph = parseDotGraph (B.pack (show dotObject)) :: G.DotGraph String
    Prelude.putStrLn $ B.unpack $ renderDot $ toDot xDotGraph -- this is not working, want to print
    -- addExtension (runGraphviz xDotGraph) Png "graph" -- this is not working, want to draw as an image
    printDocs dot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `liftIO $` to the left of `Prelude.putStrLn`, but next time paste the complete error with line numbers and such. Your do block is in the `ReaderT MongoContext IO` monad, which contains `IO` so you can do `IO` actions in it but you have to lift them first.